# Understanding of linear dependence of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm self-studying Axler's Linear Algebra and get a little confused by the definition of linear dependence/independence of polynomials. Sorry if this is too basic, but I don't really know who/where to ask.

Let $\mathbb P_m (\mathbb F)$ be the set of polynomials of degree $m$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F$.

Here is my understanding of what it means for the list of polynomials $p_{0}, p_{1}, \cdots, p_{m} \in \mathbb P_m (\mathbb F)$ to be linearly independent:

> The only choice of $a_{0}, a_{1}, \cdots, a_{m} \in \mathbb F$ that makes $\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_{i}p_{i}(x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb F$ is $a_{0} = a_{1} = \cdots = a_{m}=0$.

My confusion is on the definition of linear dependence. Does it mean:

> There exists $a_{0}, a_{1}, \cdots, a_{m} \in \mathbb F$, not all zero, such that $\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_{i}p_{i}(x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb F$,

or

> there exists $a_{0}, a_{1}, \cdots, a_{m} \in \mathbb F$, not all zero, such that $\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_{i}p_{i}(x)=0$, for some $x \in \mathbb F$?

(I suppose for the latter, proving linear dependence can be done by finding a specific $x$ followed by looking for the non-zero $a_{i}$ that works in this specific case; whereas for the former, I need to generalise the proof to cover all $x$). Thanks for your time!

Comment: Strictly speaking, it means neither. Yet, as Axler conflates the meanings of “polynomial” and “polynomial function”, in his (mistaken) definition he means the former, i.e., a finite set of polynomials over $\mathbb F$ is called linearly dependent if some non-trivial $\mathbb F$-linear combination of them is the zero polynomial (the zero function that maps every $x\in\mathbb F$ to zero).

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $0$ denote the additive identity of $V$. Then a list of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n\in V$ is said to linearly dependent if there exist scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n$, not all zero, such that $$a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=0$$

In the case of the vector space $P_m(F)$(working with the definitions provided in the book, where a polynomial is defined to be a function), the additive identity is the zero polynomial $$0(x)=0\text{ for all $x\in F$}$$ So, by definition of the linear dependence, a list of polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_k\in P_m(F)$ is linearly dependent if there exist scalars $a_1,\dots,a_k$, not all zero, such that $$a_1p_1(x)+\dots+a_kp_k(x)=0(x)\text{ for all $x\in F$}$$

Hope this clears things up!

Answer (score -1):

It is the latter.  "0" is the "0 polynomial", equal to 0 for all x,  not just a value for some x.

Comment: Sorry, you probably mean it is the former (= 1st one), not the latter (= 2dn one), I believe. I.e. you mean $\exists (a_i)_{i=0\dots m},$ not all zeros, $\forall x \in \mathbb{F}, \sum_{i=0}^{m}a_{i}p_{i}(x)=0$, not $\exists (a_i)_{i=0\dots m},$ not all zeros, $\exists x \in \mathbb{F}, \sum_{i=0}^{m}a_{i}p_{i}(x)=0$, isn't it?